# Is there a general method for computing finitely generated normalizers?

Tags: gr.group-theory, lie-groups

I'm looking to compute normalizers of finite subgroups of $\mathrm{GL}(n, \mathbb{Z})$ and its possible that they are infinite but they are always finitely presented. For $\mathrm{GL}(n, \mathbb{Z})$ the solution is actually described here:

https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1973-27-121/S0025-5718-1973-0333025-7/S0025-5718-1973-0333025-7.pdf

My question is whether there's a general method for computing finitely presented normalizers when the group and subgroup presentations are known? The subgroup is finite.

Comment: Could you clarify a couple of things? The title says “finitely generated” but the question says “finitely presented”. Also, do you want a procedure that, given a subgroup, outputs a generating set for the normaliser? Or a presentation for the normaliser?

Comment: If your input consists just of finite presentations of the group and subgroup then the problem is almost certainly theoretically undecidable.

Comment: @DerekHolt I'm pretty sure that this is decidable (even the stronger version, i.e., outputting presentations). These are lattices in "computable" Zariski closed $\mathbf{Q}$-defined real subgroups of $\mathrm{GL}_n$. The geometric arguments that these groups are finitely presented should (with enough work) yield explicit presentations.

Comment: @HJRW Finitely generated, a systematic procedure that outputs generators.

Comment: @YCor That sounds right. I was misinterpreting the question. I had thought that the final paragraph was about general finitely presented groups rather than subgroups of ${\rm GL}(n,{\mathbb Z})$, but I read it too quickly!

Comment: @DerekHolt I'm trying to solve for $GL(n, \mathbb{Z})$ but I was hoping for an algorithm that just uses the group and subgroup presentations, and doesn't refer to properties on $GL(n, \mathbb{Z})$ as much as possible.

Comment: @Jim Well, if you don't use any properties of $\operatorname{GL}(n, \mathbb{Z})$, then virtually every problem you can pose about computing normalisers will be undecidable (this can be extracted from the Baumslag-Boone-Neumann strengthening of Adian-Rabin).

Comment: As a specific proof of undecidability in general: let $G=\langle \mathbf{x}\mid\mathbf{r}\rangle$ have undecidable word problem, and consider the group $H$ with presentation $\langle \mathbf{x}, y, t\mid\mathbf{r}, t^{-1}yt=yw(\mathbf{x})\rangle$, which is an HNN-extension of $G\ast\mathbb{Z}$. Here, the normaliser of $y$ in $H$ is $\langle y\rangle$ if $w(\mathbf{x})\neq1$ in $G$, and is $\langle y, t\rangle$ if $w(\mathbf{x})=1$ in $G$. As we cannot determine in general if $w(\mathbf{x})=1$, determining the normaliser is also undecidable.

Comment: @ADL Yes, but note that OP asks for normalisers of finite subgroups (no major obstruction, but eg Novikov’s group with undecidable word problem is torsion-free).

Comment: @Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda Yes, my comment is about the most general situation possible, and certainly does not answer the question!

Comment: @Jim: as the comments show, no general method is possible. You will have to use specific facts about $GL_n(\mathbb{Z})$, as explained in the paper you link to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here’s a strategy that sometimes works but is likely hopeless in general. Suppose $G$ acts on a complex $K$ with the property that each finite subgroup of $G$ fixes a point. For example, if the complex $K$ happens to enjoy the CAT(0) property, this will be satisfied.

In this situation, suppose $H$ is a finite subgroup. It has a fixed subspace $X \subset K$. Each $g \in G$ sends the fixed-point set $X$ for $H$ to the fixed-point set for $gHg^{-1}$, so if $g$ normalizes $H$, then $g$ actually preserves $X$, and if $X$ has the property that $H$ is its pointwise stabilizer, the converse holds; namely, if $g$ preserves $X$, then $g$ normalizes $H$.

Anyway, there are standard techniques to attempt to compute a presentation of a group from its action on a simply connected complex, so if $X$ enjoys this property, then you might attempt to compute a presentation for $N_G(H)$ this way.